# How do I set a pin's location on the user's current location?

Tags: objective-c, annotations, location

```
//.h file
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
@interface MapMain : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>
{
MKMapView *mapView;
CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

-(IBAction)GetLocation:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)SetPin:(id)sender;

@end

//code within .m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
self.mapView.delegate = self;
[self.mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}


-(NSString *)deviceLocation {
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"latitude: %f longitude: %f",    locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
}


-(IBAction)SetPin:(id)sender
{
NSLog(@"%@", [self deviceLocation]);

Pin *newPin = [[Pin alloc]init];
newPin.coordinate = 
newPin.title = @"Title Tester";
newPin.subtitle = @"Sub Tester";
[self.mapView addAnnotation:newPin];

}
```

Within "Set Pin", i want to to set the newPin's coordinates to the users current location. I found the function "deviceLocation", but don't know how to call it and use it within my SetPin function.

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following methods within `MKMapViewDelegate` section in MKMapView.h

```
- (void)mapViewWillStartLocatingUser:(MKMapView *)mapView NS_AVAILABLE(10_9, 4_0);
- (void)mapViewDidStopLocatingUser:(MKMapView *)mapView NS_AVAILABLE(10_9, 4_0);
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation NS_AVAILABLE(10_9, 4_0);
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didFailToLocateUserWithError:(NSError *)error NS_AVAILABLE(10_9, 4_0);
```

Specifically `mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:` From there you can get the users location and set annotations to your hearts content.